# Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found when trying to access live events on a document in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When using StreamBuilder for accessing real time data of a document in Firestore it is giving error as below.

```
W/DynamiteModule(11369): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(11369): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(11369): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

as used below

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .doc("dkYhiL8d89I3qpu4mKvu")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapShot) {
            if (snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Text(snapShot.data?.data().toString() ?? "");
            }
            return Text("No data available");
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

but when adding listen() to the snapshot it is responding to every document change and without any error

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc("dkYhiL8d89I3qpu4mKvu")
          .snapshots().listen((event)=>print(event.data()));
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a stacktrace? The stack trace will likely give a better idea of what the origin of the error is.